# glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 1

Tags: webgl

*Note: the general question has been asked before, but this sort of error seems to really depend on specifics. Apologies if this is indeed a duplicate*

I am getting the "out of range" error for the attribute `a_Morph_0`, despite checking numerous things:

1. The attribute exists in the shader
2. I am using VAO's, and tried releasing it (setting to null)
3. The pipeline works fine with other data
4. I encountered this error previously and fixed by just chopping stuff off the *fragment* shader, but that didn't help this time
5. Switching the order of `a_Position` and `a_Morph_0` changes the error accordingly, i.e. it still references a_Morph_0.

The vertex shader code:

```
attribute vec4 a_Position;
attribute vec4 a_Morph_0;
attribute vec4 a_Morph_1;
uniform float u_MorphWeights[2];

uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;
uniform mat4 u_ModelMatrix;    

void main() {
    vec4 m_Position = a_Position;

    m_Position += (u_MorphWeights[0] * a_Morph_0);
    m_Position += (u_MorphWeights[1] * a_Morph_1);

    gl_Position = u_MVPMatrix * m_Position;
}
```

Some relevant data:

- data for `elements`: Uint16Array(3) [0, 1, 2]
- data for attribute `a_Position`: Float32Array(9) [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0]
- data for attribute `a_Morph_0`: Float32Array(9) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0]
- data for attribute `a_Morph_1`: Float32Array(9) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]

The draw call is with count of 3. Specifically:

`gl.drawElements(4, 3, 5123, 0);`

Screenshot from Spector:

[image]

**Anything else I should be checking?**

Comment: "data for elements: Uint16Array(3) [0, 1, 2]"

Answer (score 0):

I found my bug - if we look at the Spector output, the morphs attributes have a non-zero offsetPointer, i.e. 36 and 72

This isn't correct in my current implementation since the data is sliced to the correct segment *before* uploading it to the GPU buffer. Therefore the offset should always be 0.